# Can I use edge type without connection types in GraphQL?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graphql, graphql-js

I need the edge type to add additional fields between two nodes. But I don't need connections for pagination.

Can I use edge without connections in GraphQL? What is the best practice of doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing about edge types is special - just define a new object type and refer to that instead of the other type directly. Just like you might define a join table in SQL. So let's say you start out with (in the GraphQL schema language):

```
type User {
  bestFriend: User
}
```

Then you want to add something about the friendship, you can create a type for that:

```
type User {
  bestFriend: Friendship
}

type Friendship {
  friend: User
  startTime: Date
  commonPhotos: [Photo]
}
```

Now the `Friendship` type works just like an edge.